# Feature names across several lines using AVM package

Tags: avm

Is there a way to define feature names in the AVM package that span over multiple lines? In the MWE below, the alignment in the AVM goes horribly wrong since the topmost feature name is too long to fit in a single line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{avm}

\begin{document}

\title{This is a test document.}
\author{Sebastian Sulger}
\maketitle

\section{Current Annotation Scheme}

\begin{avm}
\[ {\sc voice} & \[ {\sc actor/undergoer/locative/benefactive/instrumental/passive/middle-passive} & +/--\\
{\sc passive-type} & personal/impersonal/adversative\\
{\sc middle-type} & +/dir-refl/indir-refl/caus-refl/anti-caus\]
\]
\end{avm}

\end{document}
```

Adjusting it with a manual linebreak as in the MWE below did not help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{avm}

\begin{document}

\title{This is a test document.}
\author{Sebastian Sulger}
\maketitle

\section{Current Annotation Scheme}

\begin{avm}
\[ {\sc voice} & \[ {\sc actor/undergoer/locative/benefactive/instrumental/passive/middle}\\
{\sc passive} & +/--\\
{\sc passive-type} & personal/impersonal/adversative\\
{\sc middle-type} & +/dir-refl/indir-refl/caus-refl/anti-caus\]
\]
\end{avm}

\end{document}
```

Edit: I ended up using the "solution" below, where I set the font size to `footnotesize`, so that the long feature name fits the paper, as well as replace the alignment character `&` by a couple of spaces, so that subsequent lines are not aligned. (One could also do it the other way around - using spaces in the long feature line and `&` in the subsequent lines.)

Let me know if you can think of a better way to do this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{avm}

\begin{document}

\title{This is a test document.}
\author{Sebastian Sulger}
\maketitle

\section{Current Annotation Scheme}

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{avm}
\[ {\sc voice} & \[ {\sc actor/undergoer/locative/benefactive/instrumental/passive/middle passive} & +/--\\
{\sc passive}~~~~+/--\\
{\sc passive-type}~~~~personal/impersonal/adversative\\
{\sc middle-type}~~~~+/dir-refl/indir-refl/caus-refl/anti-caus\]
\]
\end{avm}
\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No - that will not be possible since I need all of these options inside the feature `VOICE`. Would one be able to use an evironment such as `multline` here?

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer rather than editing it into your question. It is really confusing this way! (If you aren't happy with it, which I understand, of course don't accept it to mark the question satisfactorily answered.)